# problems with encoding (php)

Tags: php, encoding

My site have a utf-8 encoding (Drupal).

I use **include** function to integrate my page with 3rd party service.
But this gives a bad result - bad encoding for include part of page.

i try this, but this don't give any result:

```
iconv("ASCII","utf-8",include("http://new.velo-travel.ru/themes/themex/spectrum_view.php?$QUERY_STRING"))
```

before this i use `mb_detect_encoding` to know encoding

this is **included file**:

```
$url = 'http://young.spectrum.ru/cgi-bin/programs_form.pl';
$params = $_GET;
if ($params){
  $url .= '?';
  foreach ($params as $key => $value) $url .= '&' . $keys . '=' . urlencode($value);
}

#$content = file_get_contents($url);
echo iconv("cp-1251","utf-8", $url);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `include` function doesn't return a string (unless you actually call `return` in the included file), it literally includes the content to your source code. So if the server returns PHP source code, it would be interpreted on your server (which basically means the owners of "new.velo-travel.ru" would have control over your site :)).

Also, as Augenfeind pointed out, the page is in windows-1251. So, you probably want:

```
echo iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8", file_get_contents("http://new.velo-travel.ru/themes/themex/spectrum_view.php?$QUERY_STRING"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the page you are including is delivered as "windows-1251" by the web server of velo-travel.ru.

So you might want to change the encoding in your iconv-command?!

Answer (score 1):

Try mb_convert_encoding or iconv for all outputted text and literals in your file. For example:

```
$text = mb_convert_encoding( $oldText, 'UTF-8', "ISO-8859-1" );
```

or

```
 $text = iconv( "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $oldText);
```

Hope you get it working!